CGPoint array conforming to VectorArithmetic does not work
I am trying to make CGPoint array conform to VectorArithmetic using this piece of code:
import SwiftUI

struct AnimatableCGPointVector: VectorArithmetic {
    static var zero = AnimatableCGPointVector(values: [.zero])

    static func - (lhs: AnimatableCGPointVector, rhs: AnimatableCGPointVector) -> AnimatableCGPointVector {
        let values = zip(lhs.values, rhs.values)
            .map { lhs, rhs in lhs.animatableData - rhs.animatableData }
            .map { CGPoint(x: $0.first, y: $0.second) }
        return AnimatableCGPointVector(values: values)
    }

    static func -= (lhs: inout AnimatableCGPointVector, rhs: AnimatableCGPointVector) {
        for i in 0..<min(lhs.values.count, rhs.values.count) {
            lhs.values[i].animatableData -= rhs.values[i].animatableData
        }
    }

    static func + (lhs: AnimatableCGPointVector, rhs: AnimatableCGPointVector) -> AnimatableCGPointVector {
        let values = zip(lhs.values, rhs.values)
            .map { lhs, rhs in lhs.animatableData + rhs.animatableData }
            .map { CGPoint(x: $0.first, y: $0.second) }
        return AnimatableCGPointVector(values: values)
    }

    static func += (lhs: inout AnimatableCGPointVector, rhs: AnimatableCGPointVector) {
        for i in 0..<min(lhs.values.count, rhs.values.count) {
            lhs.values[i].animatableData += rhs.values[i].animatableData
        }
    }

    var values: [CGPoint]

    mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        for i in 0..<values.count {
            values[i].animatableData.scale(by: rhs)
        }
    }

    var magnitudeSquared: Double {
        values
            .map { $0.animatableData.magnitudeSquared }
            .reduce(0.0, +)
    }
}

but, only the first point moves with animation. I have no idea what is wrong.... Please anyone help me with this.
here is the full code.
struct ContentView4: View {
    @State var points: AnimatableCGPointVector = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 24) {
            GeometryReader {
                let size = $0.size
                
                LineShape(
                    points: points
                )
                .stroke(.orange, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 32, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .onAppear {
                    points = AnimatableCGPointVector(values: one(size: size))
                }
                .overlay {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation(.bouncy(duration: 0.4, extraBounce: 0.3)) {
                                points = AnimatableCGPointVector(values: one(size: size))
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("one")
                        })
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation(.bouncy(duration: 0.4, extraBounce: 0.3)) {
                                points = AnimatableCGPointVector(values: two(size: size))
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("two")
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 320, height: 320)
    }
    
    
    func one(size: CGSize) -> [CGPoint] {
        let p1 = CGPoint(x: 90, y: -70)
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 42)
        let p3 = CGPoint(x: 75, y: 30)
                
        return [p1, p2, p3]
    }
    
    
    func two(size: CGSize) -> [CGPoint] {
        let p1 = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 320)
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: 80, y: 50)
        let p3 = CGPoint(x: 25, y: 45)
        
        return [p1, p2, p3]
    }
}

struct LineShape: Shape {
    var points: AnimatableCGPointVector
    
    var animatableData: AnimatableCGPointVector {
        get { points }
        set { points = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { p in
            p.addLines(points.values)
        }
    }
}

I tried to do the best I can, but I am new to VectorArithmetic, so I am still learning what actually happens.

I haven't tried your code, but I am sure the problem is at least partly, if not entirely, due to your use of zip (and min).
Your one and two methods return three-element arrays, but your AnimatableCGPointVector.zero method returns a one-element array. When you zip a three-element array with a one-element array, it returns a one-element array, which only contains the first element of the three-element array.
So any time SwiftUI combines one of your vectors with a zero vector, the answer is a one-element vector.
Try modifying the binary operator methods so they extend the shorter operand with more CGPoint.zero values instead of truncating the longer operand:
struct AnimatableCGPointVector {
    var values: [CGPoint]

    static func zip(
        _ a: Self,
        _ b: Self,
        with combine: (CGPoint, CGPoint) -> CGPoint
    ) -> Self {
        var answer = Self(values: [])
        var aIt = a.values.makeIterator()
        var bIt = b.values.makeIterator()
        while true {
            switch (aIt.next(), bIt.next()) {
            case (nil, nil):
                return answer
            case (.some(let aEl), nil):
                answer.values.append(combine(aEl, .zero))
            case (nil, .some(let bEl)):
                answer.values.append(combine(.zero, bEl))
            case (.some(let aEl), .some(let bEl)):
                answer.values.append(combine(aEl, bEl))
            }
        }
    }
}

extension AnimatablePair where First == CGFloat, Second == CGFloat {
    var cgPoint: CGPoint { CGPoint(x: first, y: second) }
}

extension AnimatableCGPointVector: VectorArithmetic {
    static var zero = AnimatableCGPointVector(values: [.zero])

    static func - (lhs: AnimatableCGPointVector, rhs: AnimatableCGPointVector) -> AnimatableCGPointVector {
        return zip(lhs, rhs) {
            ($0.animatableData - $1.animatableData).cgPoint
        }
    }

    static func -= (lhs: inout AnimatableCGPointVector, rhs: AnimatableCGPointVector) {
        lhs = lhs - rhs
    }

    static func + (lhs: AnimatableCGPointVector, rhs: AnimatableCGPointVector) -> AnimatableCGPointVector {
        return zip(lhs, rhs) {
            ($0.animatableData + $1.animatableData).cgPoint
        }
    }

    static func += (lhs: inout AnimatableCGPointVector, rhs: AnimatableCGPointVector) {
        lhs = lhs + rhs
    }

    mutating func scale(by rhs: Double) {
        for i in 0..<values.count {
            values[i].animatableData.scale(by: rhs)
        }
    }

    var magnitudeSquared: Double {
        values
            .map { $0.animatableData.magnitudeSquared }
            .reduce(0.0, +)
    }
}


This may work sufficiently for the Animatable protocol, but it does feel very weird. If a has a lower dimension than b, then a + b - b != a, and for any dimension other than 1, a - a != .zero. Adding a custom zero-extending == may be sufficient to fix all the weirdness (it wasn't obvious how to build it with the current zip, though; that kind of tripped me up). I'd also be tempted to make .zero an empty array just to avoid any specialness about one-dimentional vectors.

Wow! It completely worked! I had no idea about what is wrong, but thank you much. and I got to know about useful API such as makeIterator() Highly appreciate
